# EXIT trap is ignored on Ctrl-C when PID == 1

Tags: busybox, alpine-linux, exit, trap, interrupt

`a.sh`:

```bsh
trap 'echo cleanup' EXIT
sleep 3
```

To reproduce, press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> before the script finishes:

```
$ docker run --rm -itv $PWD:/app -w /app alpine:3.14 sh a.sh
^Ccleanup

$ docker run --rm -itv $PWD:/app -w /app alpine:3.14 sh
/app # sh a.sh
^C
```

Can you explain this?

Comment: What happens if you instead of `EXIT` trap `INT`, which is the signal sent by `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: @they Apparently the handler is invoked in both cases. But I'm experimenting with signals to come up with some sort of more or less universal approach for a cleanup in scripts. So at the moment I'm more interested in "what's going on," than in "how to solve it."

Comment: see this https://newbedev.com/exit-trap-in-dash-vs-ksh-and-bash

Comment: @zevzek But they do, depending on how you invoke a script. Although normally [they don't](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/c599da097ae610066ff5e3106150ed37). About the universal approach, I meant the one that works for the shells I'm using. But even then I run into corner cases I don't know how to deal with. So maybe indeed it makes sense to give up.